# How to replace all occurencies of char with elements from array?

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I have following string:

```
$sql = sql_prepare("UPDATE `test` SET `item1` = ?, `item2` = ?, `item3` = ?", array(50, 55, 60));
```

I need to create "sql_prepare" function that will match all occurencies of '?' char and replace with elements from array, so final sql will be:

```
UPDATE `test` SET `item1` = 50, `item2` = 55, `item3` = 60
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don you use _real_ prepated statements instead? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @KingCrunch because they are slow and inconvenient to use and insufficient to protect from an injection?

Comment: @donkeyKong: Why reinvent the wheel, when there's plenty of database classes both built in (mysqli, PDO) and third party (mdb2, zend_db, etc)?

Comment: @Col: Sharapnel: Can you back that statement up with some facts please?  (because if there are flaws in PHP's prepared statements and the amount of protection they offer against SQL injection I'd genuinely like to know)

Comment: Maybe I found a solution:
    function sql_prepare($sql, $params)
    {
        $sql = preg_replace('/\?/e', 'escape(array_shift($params))', $sql);
        return $sql;
    }

Comment: @GordonM If you provide me a link to simple MySQL wrapper that supports prepared statements, that would be cool. Again, "simple" is the keyword.

Comment: @GordonM it is quite obvious - prepared statements has nothing to do with identifiers, thus, one cannot say it's complete protection. While your own db class can offer it.

Comment: @shrapnel: I've not found prepared statements to be particularly inconvenient, they're not slower to such an extent as to be apparent in most general cases (that I've noticed, certainly not to an extent where they'd make the application unresponsive), and as far as I'm aware their parameters are always properly escaped when executed, making SQL injection difficult.  If this isn't the case then please let me know.

Comment: @GordonM If you want to have someone notified of your comment, you have to quote at least first 3 letters of the nickname you are addressing to after `@` symbol. Otherwise the other party won't be notified of your comment. Yeah, the speed doesn't matter, it is merely to counter the 'prepared a faster' well-known argument. The key word of my previous comment is **identifier**.

Answer (score 0):

Why try to fake a prepared statement with the legacy mysql_* API, when both mysqli and PDO implement real prepared statements?

PDO example:

```
if ($prepped = $pdo -> prepare ('UPDATE `test` SET `item1` = ?, `item2` = ?, `item3` = ?'))
{
    $res = $prepped -> execute (array (50, 55 ,60));
}
```

Comment: Moooom, why PHP allowed to fake a prepared statement while I am not? ;-)

Comment: 1) there's no need to be rude, 2) please stop acting as if any issues there are with PDO prepared statements are self-evident and explain exactly what's wrong with them. If there are indeed issues in PDO and/or mysqli, then the wider community needs to know, and I myself really want to know in order to avoid any issues this could lead to in my own projects.

Comment: Could you please be so kind to explain, what is the rudeness in my comment? I am not a native speaker and may be overlooked some expression. I'll be glad to correct it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well moooom, at first glance, looks like mooooan (drawn out moan), which make it look like the comment you made is disparaging, or sarcastic.  Sorry for not noticing it wasn't mooooan, but it does look like that.  (BTW, what does moooom mean anyway?)

Comment: I was trying to mock a childish complaint to the mom, when a child isn't allowed to do something that others do. It was merely a joke, not intended to offend anyone. PDO (not PHP - my mistake) do fake prepared statements as well by default. It does the substitution internally and send the usual query to mysql server. You have to turn native prepared statements support explicitly.

Comment: Can you point to a page that backs this claim up?  How do you enable them if they're not enabled by default?  Is it just mysql that's affected?  Postgres doesn't seem to be as far as I'm aware.  I'm doing a lot of google searches to try and find something to back your claims up but I'm not turning anything up that corroborates your claims.

Comment: I have no article but my own experience. at least in the 5.3.0 it has native support turned off for mysql, so I had to turn it on explicitly, by setting ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES attribute. You can test it yourself, just create a query with intentional error and run it and see the error message. it you see ? marks in the quoted query part - there is no emulation. if you see the actual data substituted - there is emulation mode on.

Answer (score -1):

for the such a simple replacement you can use sprintf format:

```
$sql = vsprintf("UPDATE `test` SET `item1` = %d, `item2` = %d, `item3` = %d", 
                 array(50, 55, 60));
```

however, for the real life usage, it is better to make placeholders of different types

here is the code from my db class

```
private function prepareQuery($args)
{
    $raw = $query = array_shift($args);
    preg_match_all('~(\?[a-z?])~',$query,$m,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $pholders = $m[1];
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($pholders as $i => $p)
    {
        if ($p[0] != '??')
        {
             $count++;
        }
    }
    if ( $count != count($args) )
    {
        throw new E_DB_MySQL_parser("Number of args (".count($args).") doesn't match number of placeholders ($count) in [$raw]");
    }
    $shift  = 0;
    $qmarks = 0;
    foreach ($pholders as $i => $p)
    {
        $pholder = $p[0];
        $offset  = $p[1] + $shift;
        if ($pholder != '??')
        {
            $value   = $args[$i-$qmarks];
        }
        switch ($pholder)
        {
            case '?n':
                $value = $this->escapeIdent($value);
                break;
            case '?s':
                $value = $this->escapeString($value);
                break;
            case '?i':
                $value = $this->escapeInt($value);
                break;
            case '?a':
                $value = $this->createIN($value);
                break;
            case '?u':
                $value = $this->createSET($value);
                break;
            case '??':
                $value = '?';
                $qmarks++;
                break;
            default:
                throw new E_DB_MySQL_parser("Unknown placeholder type ($pholder) in [$raw]");
        }
        $query = substr_replace($query,$value,$offset,2);
        $shift+= strlen($value) - strlen($pholder);
    }
    $this->lastquery = $query;
    return $query;
}
```

I have to admit that escaping `?` marks solution is not hat elegant but that's what I've got so far.

Comment: I have a code where I detect variable types and escapes them if needed.

Comment: lol, you didn't get the point :) it is not about variable type. it is about *placeholder* type. Your variable type detection may fail you.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the point of placing different placeholders. How variable type detection may fail?

Comment: you can see it right in this very code. it can produce a SET statement for you, out of an array. Same for the IN statement. it can escape an identifier for you. that's the point of the typed placeholders. Type detection may fail just because of wrong type. say, GET variables are always strings.

Comment: I prefer doing SET and IN statements manually.
Regarding datatypes - you're correct regarding GET variables. But when I need something treated right, I'll just do typecasting. Escaping will work as expected then.

Comment: See, typed placeholders to A LOT of work for you - all that "I'll do that manually". But of course it is up to you what to choose. Personally, I am too lazy to do repetitive tasks manually

Comment: Anyway, there is also the first code snippet that answers your question exactly.

Comment: But you do the some type of typecasting too (in queries ?s and ?i). Anyway, typecasting needs to be done at some point, do you agree?