# PDO LIMIT and EMULATE_PREPARES(false)

Tags: php, pdo

I'm currently learning `php` and I'm using `PDO` to handle my database. While trying to use `LIMIT` in a query i encountered a problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''0', '25'' at line 1

After some 'research' the solution was to add this attribute to my `PDO`:

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
```

Now my script looks like this(and the `LIMIT` works):

```
try {

    $attr = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name', 'root', '', $attr);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    exit($e->getMessage());

}

$rows = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT ?, ?");
$rows->execute([0, 25]);
```

But my question is what does `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` actually do? And is it a good solution? Does it affect in any way shape or form the level of security of that prepared statement? Is there another solution that might do a better job when it comes to using `LIMIT` within a prepared statement?

Thank you! :D

Comment: emma please check the answers of this thread.I hope you will get answer:-[PDO MySQL: Use PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not)

Comment: Hey @AlivetoDie, i saw that question but i can't figure out what EMULATE_PREPARES actually does from it :(

Comment: PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES Enables or disables emulation of prepared statements. Some drivers do not support native prepared statements or have limited support for them. Use this setting to force PDO to either always emulate prepared statements (if TRUE and emulated prepares are supported by the driver), or to try to use native prepared statements (if FALSE). It will always fall back to emulating the prepared statement if the driver cannot successfully prepare the current query. Requires bool.  Check here:- [PDO::setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Comment: Hey @AlivetoDie,first of all thank you for taking time to help me :D. I saw that on php manual too but what does "emulating" a prepare statement means? :-s i don't get that X_X. If it is on off it will affect the security of my prepare statement? :-s Thank youuu! :D

Comment: check this answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8298402/4248328 . it will make things clear out to you

Comment: @AlivetoDie, thank you:D - one last question: so basically when i turn off(false) the EMULATE_PREPARES i'm actually starting to use a real prepared statement which basically means better security, is that conclusion right? :-s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180653/discussion-between-emma-and-alive-to-die).